# how to call ajax parallel request

Tags: php, ajax

In my project I am creating a zip file of too many files and it's taking too much time for a response. As a result, other requests are going in into pending state and users have too wait for the response.

Comment: call your procedure from XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Request Example:

```
// First Request
$.get("/first-request/", function(resOfFirstRequest) {

  // Second Request
  $.get("/second-request/", function(resOfSecondRequest) {

    // Third Request
    $.getScript("/third-request/", function() {

      console.log(resOfFirstRequest);
      console.log(resOfSecondRequest);

      // All Ready So Code Here       

    });

  });

});
```

You should apply this. Hope it will help you.

Refrence [here](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/).

**Update:**

```
$.when(

  // First One

).then(function() {

  // All is ready so Code here

});
```

So in this case your first request is running and after completion your second request will response.

Comment: cant call like this .second request will not call all the time it will be execute only if user call for it ex.if user search any thing in between the the first request is running.in this scenario the second request will response only after the completion of first request but i want it at a time and it should not need to wait for first request response.

Comment: Put your code over there. So we resolved your issue.

Comment: Check updated answer. Please up vote and accept the answer if it solves your purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but i dont want to wait for first request's completion.

Comment: This is your words "in this scenario the second request will response only after the completion of first request". Please make sure what you want to ask!